# Wpf DataGrid DoubleClick has weird behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, double-click

I am working with Wpf DataGrid. I have handled MouseDoubleClick event of DataGrid to open the record in detail in separate page. So the functionality should be like I double click on a record and it should open in separate page. Currently When I double-click on the DataGrid Header(column header) or on ScrollBar it takes double-click of the selected row(selected record). I want it to take double click of row if only double-clicked on the row. Any help please!!

Answer (score 3):

Try to handle `LoadingRow` event in DataGrid and then the `DoubleClick` event in every row:

```
private void dataGrid1_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Row_MouseDoubleClick);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When resorting the DataGrid (clicking on column headers) the LoadingRow event is fired again sometimes.

I had to unsubscribe and resubscribe to the MouseDoubleClick to make this work:

```
private void dataGrid1_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e) {
    e.Row.MouseDoubleClick -= Row_MouseDoubleClick;
    e.Row.MouseDoubleClick += Row_MouseDoubleClick;
}
```